# HTML Tags for email and link to other sections on page

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

I am writing a HTML page and my requirements are as follows:

1. HTML Page contains some email ID's and when clicked on those EmailID's... it should open new page of the outlook.
2. Page has certains sections and when clicked on that.. it should reach out to the respected paragraph/section.
   Ex: click to Link to go to the .... section

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For email address link

```
<a href="mailto:youremailaddress">Email Me</a>
```

fore link navigation

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

more about navigation with in page : http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/text/internallinks.html

Answer (score 1):

Linking to sections:

```
<a href="#sectionId">Go to X</a>

<h2 id="sectionId">X</h2>
```

This way you can link to anything that has an ID, be it a header, a paragraph, a DIV or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at  tag (Anchor). You'll get what you need...
mailto will suffice your e-mail needs and hash tags will solve the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<a href="mailto:you@yourdomain.com">Email</a>
```

This should open the new window on your email client (outlook or whatever you have set).